# Chrome ARC Welder Logcat

Tags: android, adb, logcat, google-chrome-arc

I am trying to get logcat working for Chrome ARC Welder. I run the command  plugin.shell('adbd') and it starts successfully. My question is when I run the 'adb logcat' command. I am supposed to run that in the JavaScript console or adb when working with any android application. When I run it in the JavaScript Console I get:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifierVM268:847 InjectedScript._evaluateOnVM268:780 InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrapVM268:646 InjectedScript.evaluate

And when from adb directly, it just sits waiting but I get no output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on a desktop machine with the android SDK you can run 'adb logcat' from a command line when ARC has adb enabled, it will show up as a device or emulator. If you just want to run it from the JavaScript console you can just run the logcat shell command directly without adbd:

> plugin.shell('logcat');

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc#bestpractices