# Google Chrome ARC intent-filter crash

Tags: android, android-intent, google-chrome-arc, chromebook

I try to implement launch app from intent filter on ARC using that code :

```
<activity
        android:name=".package.etc.MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|fontScale"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/myactivity_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
        <data android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

On Android Tablet, it works. But on Chrome ARC app crashes.
Is Chrome ARC supports that ?

**EDIT**

I got that crash

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException There is no Activity which handles filePath = file:///data/data/org.chromium.arc/external/C1373AC2527597D1C0BC66486DCC787F/Gra‌​nizo.pdf mimeType=application/pdf 

org.chromium.arc.helper.FileHandlerLaunchHelperActivity.buildLaunchIntent (FileHandlerLaunchHelperActivity.java:122)
org.chromium.arc.helper.FileHandlerLaunchHelperActivity.onMessage (FileHandlerLaunchHelperActivity.java:162)
org.chromium.arc.ArcMessageBridge$1.handleMessage (ArcMessageBridge.java:75)
org.chromium.arc.ArcMessageBridgeService$3.run (ArcMessageBridgeService.java:238)
```

**EDIT 2**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.package.activities.MyActivity_"
        android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|fontScale"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:label="@string/myactivity_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
        <data android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: What does LogCat show you?

Comment: Can't see logcat on chromebook

Comment: You certainly used to be able to. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29451047/115145 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/29564350/115145 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/32951857/115145

Comment: All right, please see my edit, I put the crash

Comment: Where and how are you starting this activity, that is generating this crash?

Comment: Activity is declared in Manifest (see my second edit) and when an user click on a PDF file it should open this activity. On tablet it works, but not on ARC

Comment: "when an user click on a PDF file" -- click where? In another activity of yours? If so, why not use an explicit `Intent`, rather than relying on this `<intent-filter>`?

Comment: No, in a file explorer. This is why i'm using intent filter.

Comment: Is the file explorer in your APK? Or is this some other app that is not in your APK?

Comment: No ! For example I got a PDF file on my SD card, I click on the file and open it with my app.

Comment: "I click on the file" -- that's not very helpful. I asked where this file explorer is. Is this file explorer in your app? Is the file explorer some other APK that you converted to ARC and is running in this same Chrome environment? Are you referring to the ChromeOS "Files" app (and if so, how are you telling it to open the PDF in your app)? Are you referring to something else that you are calling a "file explorer".

Comment: No the file explorer is not in my app, i'm refering to ARC file explorer. Right click on a file (in ARC file explorer), choose MyApplication

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that whatever "ARC file explorer" is refers to some other Android app, packaged via ARC, that is running in your Chrome/ChromeOS environment.

In that case, that app has nothing to do with your app.

It is best to think of ARC as providing separate Android emulators per ARC. Apps in one ARC do not have access to apps in other ARCs, just as apps in one emulator image do not have access to apps in other emulator images (or apps on one device do not have access to apps on a separate device). Hence, your "ARC file explorer", in its own ARC, cannot open a PDF via your app in a separate ARC.

This makes many Android apps fairly useless in the ARC environment, and hopefully is something that will be addressed in the future.